# Get random points within polygon corners?

Tags: android, google-maps, polygon

I've drawn a polygon in google maps. I would like to generate random coordinates within polygon boundaries to add some markers inside the polygon. How can I do that?

I got this link

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/163044/mapbox-how-to-generate-a-random-coordinate-inside-a-polygon

but it is a javascript code but how to get in java code.

Comment: I don't get you, you want to generate a point inside the Poligon boundaries?

Comment: yes, I want to add markers inside a polygon? I have latitude and longitude coordinates

Answer (score 4):

In Python you can generate random coordinates with in a defined polygon like below

```
import numpy as np
import random

from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point


poly = Polygon([(23.789642, 90.354714), (23.789603, 90.403000), (23.767688, 90.403597),(23.766510, 90.355448)])

def random_points_within(poly, num_points):
    min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = poly.bounds

    points = []

    while len(points) < num_points:
        random_point = Point([random.uniform(min_x, max_x), random.uniform(min_y, max_y)])
        if (random_point.within(poly)):
            points.append(random_point)

    return points


points = random_points_within(poly,1000)

for p in points:
    print(p.x,",",p.y)
```

Comment: Good solution, but inefficient if n_points >= 1000. Maybe there are some additional constraints?